# Open multiple independent terminal from a python script

Tags: python, linux, terminal, multiprocessing, multi-user

I'm trying to open from a single script multiple in order to implement a sort of multi user.The number of users is unknown a priori, so i can't use multiprocess library with starmap. I tried with gnu-terminal (i'm using elementary os) but it doeasn't work and even with screen or xterm it's the same. I only need to launch a python script like happens when i open a new terminal and i launch it writing "python3 script.py"

Answer (score 0):

On elementaryOS, you can open a new terminal with this command `io.elementary.terminal`

So you can probably try this

```
import os
os.system('io.elementary.terminal -e "python3 script.py"')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works (i modified the code because it brings me on home directory - home/user- so used a bash script that changes directory where i want to go and than stars the python script). Anyway is there a method that allows me achieve this result on all Linux distros? Event if this is a server version, for example